# Ignore upper and lower case findall in Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tree, elementtree

I have to parse XML that has Label names that may be in any case (mixed, upper, lower, etc) and I don't know what the case will be beforehand. How can I make findall be totally case insensitive in ElementTree?
The XML data looks something like the following. As you can see in the first there is "a" and in the second there is "A".

```
<VALUE FORMAT="NUM" LABEL="TABROW_Modul3Tempe.TABROW_Modul3Tempe_Temperatures.Param_Tempe_Senso_1" TEXT="Module_3_Temperature - Temperature Sensor 1" UNIT="°C">27</VALUE>
<VALUE FORMAT="NUM" LABEL="TABROW_Modul3Tempe.TABROW_Modul3Tempe_Temperatures.PAram_Tempe_Senso_2" TEXT="Module_3_Temperature - Temperature Sensor 2" UNIT="°C">28</VALUE>
```

Im searching for the Value using findall. Is there a way to ignore upper and lower case when using findall?

```
temperature = root.findall('./RESULT/SECTION/MEAS/VALUE/[@LABEL="TABROW_Modul3Tempe.TABROW_Modul3Tempe_Temperatures.PAram_Tempe_Senso_1"]')
```

Comment: Can you use .lower() or .upper() to your source xml and then find in lower o upper ? or try this ...//VALUE[lower-case(@LABEL)='your_string_in_lower']

Comment: @Wonka Is it possible to bring all the letters in an XML file to upper or lower case using .lower()? Its an huge file.

Comment: @Wonka i need to search for the exact same way as it is written in the XML file. So if i use your version i wont find the Value

Comment: Had you tried second part of my first comment? xpath with lower-case